# Data parameter ranges for Start and End dates

Tags: t-sql, date, reporting-services, null, query-string

I have a req to include Start and End date such that user should pick date range.

Start date includes NULL.

I created parameters with Date/time and allowed NULL in Start date parameter.

Also, I placed filters in Tablix for these filters.

My issue is when I select Start and end date range I don't see any data in my report.

```
Main Dataset:

    SELECT Col1, Col2, Start_Date, End_Date, Col3
    FROM  Table

Dataset 1:

SELECT DISTINCT Col1
FROM  Table

Dataset 2:

SELECT DISTINCT Col2
FROM            Table
WHERE        (Col1IN (@Param1))
ORDER BY Col2

Dataset 3:

SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM  Table
WHERE       
(Col1 IN (@Param1)) 
AND (Col2 IN (@Param2))
GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3
```

Any inputs/ideas/suggestions is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do an outer join against a calendar table that contains all the dates in your query range. That way, you'll see the dates in your results even if there's no corresponding measure for it.